# how to restore state of label visibility in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

I have been trying to figure out how to preserve and then restore the visibility state of a label in my app, but can't, for the life of me, figure it out.

I've got restoration ID's set for the view controller by checking the 'Use Storyboard ID' in the Interface Builder (and there is a Storyboard ID provided to use). I've added the `shouldSaveApplicationState` and `shouldRestoreApplicationState` functions to my AppDelegate file to return true.

Where I'm getting stuck is on the View Controller's swift file. I can't figure out how to use the `override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` to encode the visibility state and then how to use the `override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` to decode it back when it comes into view.

I have 3 labels that start off being hidden (viewDidLoad sets them all to isHidden = true). Then, depending on which button is tapped I set the appropriate label to being shown (e.g. isHidden = false). When the user exits the app I want the label that was changed to be shown to be restored when they come back to the app.

I've found the following code for different types of objects:

```
override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {

    // retrieve profile ID so that we can fetch entire profile
    profileID = Int(coder.decodeIntegerForKey(“profileID"))

    //image data
    if let imageData = coder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as? NSData {
      profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
    // name
    if let name = coder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String {
      nameTextField.text = name
    }

    super.decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
 }
```

But I can't figure out how to translate any of these object types to work with the visibility property?

Please help, this is driving me crazy! Seems like such a simple thing... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(button1.isHidden, forKey: "button1")
    coder.encode(button2.isHidden, forKey: "button2")
    coder.encode(button3.isHidden, forKey: "button3")
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
}

override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    button1.isHidden = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "button1")
    button2.isHidden = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "button2")
    button3.isHidden = coder.decodeBool(forKey: "button3")
    super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
}
```